# Open Context Menu by ctrl+menu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I'd like to open the following context menu exclusively by pressing ctrl + menu:

```
<Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Name="item0" Header="mode_0"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.ContextMenu>
```

I have another context menu which is bound to a button in the window. I want to be able to open the window-context menu whatever element is focused. To prevent that the window-context can't be opened at any time, e.g. the button is focused.

I tried to open it by:

```
Context.Menu.name.isOpened = true;
```

after checking the pressedKey-event, but the contextMenu closes right after releasing the menu button. 
Does anyone know a better .. and working way?

Comment: What is the "apps button"? Do you mean the Windows Key ?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key

Comment: Oh, the event.Key is called apps ... i mean this one : http://www.lytebyte.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/right-click-keyboard-key.jpg

Comment: Back in my day, that was called the Menu key. Which made sense, since it was used for invoking context menus. [Apparently it is also called the Application key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key). I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to disable the Menu key in your window, otherwise the OS will try to resolve it ..

Something like that:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.PreviewKeyUp += MainWindow_PreviewKeyUp;

    }

    void MainWindow_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Key == Key.Apps)
      {
        e.Handled = true;
      }
    }
```

And afterwards open your own Context Menu programmatically.

Comment: i tried to use e.handled in my eventlistener, but it didin't work though

Comment: This solved my similar problem. I had been handling `KeyDown`, which causes the context menu to close unless the key is held. Swapped to `PreviewKeyUp` and the menu works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure If I understand what you are looking for correctly.
you probably should do something like that:

define a Command

```
 OpenMenu = new RoutedUICommand("OpenMenu ", "OpenMenu ", typeof(Commands), new   InputGestureCollection { 
                new KeyGesture(Key.O, ModifierKeys.Control, "Ctrl+O") });
```

use it in your Window

```
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="local:Commands.OpenMenu "
                        Executed="OpenMenuExecuted" />
   </Window.CommandBindings>

    private void OpenMenuExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           this.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;          
    }
```

note: if you dont want the right click button opening the window `ContextMenu` you can prevent it by attaching  `ContextMenuOpening` event handler and setting the `e.Handled = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Argh, the menu button triggers on the keyUp-event ... I've been listening to keyDown-event. That's why the menu opens on the key down and getting closed by releasing the menu button.