# display contextmenu on treeview using apps key of keyboard

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have a tree view in my wpf application. The context menu of the tree node is working properly with the right click of mouse. I have a requirement where i have to open this context menu using apps key of keyboard. I have written following piece of code to open context menu but problem is that context menu gets closed as soon as apps key is released.

```
if (focusedElement.DependencyObjectType.Name == "TreeViewItem" && (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Apps)))
                {
                    TreeViewItem tvi = focusedElement as TreeViewItem;
                    ContextMenu cm = tvi.FindResource("ContextMenuKey") as ContextMenu;  
if (cm != null){
cm.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Please suggest something. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One question is where that code resides. Make sure you chose the correct event. I for one would either use `KeyUp` or a `KeyBinding` with a command. Also, just check the [`Key`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.key(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the event arguments instead of querying the keyboard.

Something that may interfere is additional event handling. Try setting [`Handled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true` after opening the menu.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was posted to another question:
[Open Context Menu by ctrl+menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330185/open-context-menu-by-ctrlmenu/18330927#18330927)

Short version: handle the `PreviewKeyUp` event.